# How can i drop shadow to top and bottom of view which is inside the table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a view inside the table view cell and I want to show shadow to that view if below situations

1. if view on first cell then drop shadow to top, left, right.
2. if view on last cell then drop shadow to bottm, left, right.
3. other wise drop shadow only on left and right.

Thank You.

Comment: the way you are asking for drop shadow doesn't really work that way, you may need to draw your shadow by yourself or use overlapping view's accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]put this code in your class

```
extension UIView {

func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
}}
```

Then call it:--

```
YourView.dropShadow(scale: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
```

And adapt the code below to the way you want for the corners that you'd like to drop shadow.

```
var shadowRect: CGRect = yourView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4) // inset top and bottom of the cell
yourView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath
```